# QuadTree Triangle insert and search

Tags: c++, data-structures, graphics, quadtree

I am trying to implement QuadTree data structure with triangle objects, so I can do ray triangle intersection. But it is querying unnecessary triangles. I don't know if that is a property of QuadTree's.

Here is my QuadTree insert code:

```
//First check if triangle is inside the node box. If it does,
//then subdivide until to insert triangle into the lowest node.
//If it doesn't insert into its child, then insert into the root's
//data.
bool insert(const Triangle& triangle, uint depth = 0) {
    if (!triangle.isInside(bound) || depth >= 10) return false;
    if (!divided) subdivide();
    //insert into root if no nodes can support it
    if (!(NW->insert(triangle, depth + 1) || NE->insert(triangle, depth + 1) ||
        SW->insert(triangle, depth + 1) || SE->insert(triangle, depth + 1))) {
        triangles.push_back(triangle);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Search code:

```
void searchTriangles(const QuadTree& tree, const Line& line, vector<Vertex>& vertices, Color color) {
    Vector2f hit;
    const Boundary* treeBounds = tree.getBound();
    //if ray doesn't intersect the box, then exit.
    if (!intersect(treeBounds->topLeft, treeBounds->bottomRight, line.p1, line.p2, hit)) return;

    //Get all the triangles from this node and childern.
    const vector<Triangle>* triangles = tree.getTriangles();
    for (const Triangle& t : *triangles) {
        vertices.push_back(Vertex(Vector2f(t.getP1()->x, t.getP1()->y), color));
        vertices.push_back(Vertex(Vector2f(t.getP2()->x, t.getP2()->y), color));
        vertices.push_back(Vertex(Vector2f(t.getP3()->x, t.getP3()->y), color));
    }
    if (!tree.subdivided()) return;
    searchTriangles(*tree.getNW(), line, vertices, color);
    searchTriangles(*tree.getNE(), line, vertices, color);
    searchTriangles(*tree.getSW(), line, vertices, color);
    searchTriangles(*tree.getSE(), line, vertices, color);
}
```

Example output:

[image: Example Output]

Comment: *//if inserted then dont need to check other ones* -- Advice -- instead of `goto`, you could have done `if (NW->insert(triangle, depth + 1) || NE->insert(triangle, depth + 1) || ... ) return true; else triangles.push_back(triangle); return false;`.  The `||` would have worked as a short-circuit evaluator.  Given that, you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: I would say your example works quite well. The reason why you see the crosses is because you insert triangles into the parents if they lie on the boundary of their children. An alternative is to insert the triangles in all the children with which they overlap. For traversal, you might then want to remember the triangles that you tested to avoid duplicates.